# Count total child of each of each branch Oracle Hierarchy

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables as follows:

- The first table stores the list of branches with Hierarchy relationship (
  father - child)
- The second stores list of children of each branch

I tried the following, but it can only count the direct children of that branch, but can not count the higher levels. I'm using oracle 11g

```
select 
   branID, count(*) - 1 as itemCount
from 
(
   select 
      connect_by_root(a.branID) as branID
   from 
      tBranch a INNER JOIN tItem b ON a.branID = b.branID     
      connect by prior a.branID = a.fatherID
) 
group by branID
```

Comment: Please show some sample data, since your problem description in words doesn't make sense. What is a "list of branches"? Never heard of that. What does "children of each branch" mean? Branches don't have children, parents have children. Etc. Instead of trying to re-word the problem, show some hypothetical sample data, it will be easier to understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, or the data model; if the first table stores the parent/child relationship, how does the second also store children? And what do you mean by higher levels - if you count levels above as well as below doesn't that just count everything? Sample data and current and expected results would be helpful. (And 'branch' is confusing as that term can refer to the hierarchy tree; I *think* you mean something else, like branches of a bank; but it isn't clear..)